# Angular : use a method from a specific service as useFactory provider for a module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular2-services

I have a module within my **Angular5** app where i m using it like this :

```
import *....
@NgModule({

  providers: [
    AuthentificationService,
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: AuthentificationService.MYMETHOD,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions, EnvVarsService, LocalStorageService, RouteNavigator, ReloadTokenEventService]
    }
  ]
})

export class AuthModule {
  constructor( ) {}

}
```

my problem is that i want to use a custom method: MYMETHOD which i defined in my **AuthentificationService**

My service is like the following :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthentificationService {

  constructor() {}

  public authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions,
                                envVarsService: EnvVarsService,
                                localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
                                router: RouteNavigator,
                                reloadTokenEventService: ReloadTokenEventService) {

    return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
      tokenName: 'X-Auth-Token',
      headerName: 'X-Auth-Token',
      noTokenScheme: true,
      noJwtError: true,
      tokenGetter: (() => this.getAccessToken(http, options, envVarsService, localStorageService, router, reloadTokenEventService)),
      globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
    }), http, options);
  }


  private getAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
         // SOME TREATMENT
    }
  }

}
```

But i seems that i can't find it **(AuthentificationService.MYMETHOD )**

**Suggestions?**

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unclear what AuthentificationService is and why it lacks the method. Is it static and bound method? Otherwise this is a mistake.

Comment: @estus you may see the update

Comment: At this point class design looks clumsy. Generally you'd want to make factory method static, because it is supposed to instantiate a class. In your case you will need to create an instance of a class that creates another instance... doesn't make much sense. Is constructor really empty? Should getAccessToken be instance method? Please, provide entire AuthentificationService , because this is related to how it can be used or refactored here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it should work using an exported function,  add AuthentificationService to deps array

```
export function myFactory(authService: AuthentificationService) {
     return () => authService.yourMethod();
}

providers: [
AuthentificationService,
{
  provide: AuthHttp,
  useFactory: myFactory,
  deps: [AuthentificationService, Http, RequestOptions, EnvVarsService, LocalStorageService, RouteNavigator, ReloadTokenEventService],
  multi: true
}
]
```